# Emberjs nested route index paramater

Tags: ember.js

How do I get access to the `params` field from my index route that I created.

Here is my router.

```
export default Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('posts', function() {
    this.resource('posts.post', {path: ':id'}, function(){
      ...
      ...
      ...
    });
  });
});
```

When I go to `/posts/1` and look at the ember inspector's view tree, I see for routes `posts.post` and `posts.post.index` both have `{id: '1'}` for their model.

In the `posts.post` route, I can do the following:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){
    console.log('params.id = ' + params.id);
  },
});
```

This prints to the console `params.id = 1`.

However, when I run that same code in the `posts.post.index` route; `params.id` is `undefined`.  As a matter of fact if I run `JSON.stringify(params)` it is empty.

How do I get access to the `params` form `posts.post.index` route.  Ideally, I would like not to have to access the `params` from the `posts.post` route.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the model of another route with `this.modelFor('posts.post')`.

Note that dynamic segments are only available to the route where they were defined. Wanting to access those from different routes is a bad smell.

Comment: But how come when I go to `/posts/1` both `posts.post` and `posts.post.index` route show `{id:1}` in the ember inspector if I do not define a model for both the routes.  Should that not mean I have access to params, even from `posts.post.index`?

Comment: I ended up setting the model on the `posts.post` route. All the sub-routes (Ex `posts.post.index`) will have access to the model. So there is no need to define the model on the sub-routes.